# Laravel 5.7: Too many redirect after Validation failed

Tags: laravel, validation, redirect, routes, middleware

I have a two step form, after the input on the first page gets validated a second page to upload a file will be displayed.

Here's the validation rules for the file input:

```
return [
        'file' => 'mimes:pdf,ps|required', 
    ];
```

When I try to submit the form without attaching a file then I get the message that I've been **redirected too many times**.

Here's also a custom middleware I created to set the locale that's needed for the urls:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
   $locale = $request->segment(1);
   app()->setLocale($locale);
   return $next($request); // this is the marked line
}
```

I have no 'get'-route for the second form-page since it will only display after the first user input is validated.
After creating a 'get'-route it still didn't work and I still got **redirected too many times**.

```
Route::post('/{locale}/ticket/{cat?}', 'TicketController@store')->name('validation');
Route::get('/{locale}/ticket/{cat?}', 'TicketController@store')->name('validation');
```

I even tried to do this:

```
Route::match(['post', 'get'], '/{locale}/ticket/{cat?},  'TicketController@store')->name('validation');
```

after reading about this, but it still didn't work and know I really don't know what to do.

I only get redirected too many times when the second validation fails, when I don't `require` the file (in the validation rule) and the validation doesn't redirect then the `upload`-method just continues as it should.

**EDIT:**

This is the upload-method in the TicketController as requested:

```
public function upload(ValidateUploadedFile $request, $cat = '') {
  // handle first user input
  $file = $request->validated();
  // handle storage of data       
}
```

I don't have any idea how to solve this issue.
If any more code or information is needed to help me, please tell me!

Comment: Can you show the `TicketController@store` function?

Comment: @Jerodev I meant the `upload` instead of the `store` function, sorry. But there's only one line that makes a problem, I added it to the question